# Arrays saved with Jquery & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Here I am saving the following array to a text file, it is dynamic and can have one value or 1000 values, how is it possible for me to read this back into html?

```
questionbanknames This Is The Hard Onequestion-1 1?questiontype-1 manualanswer-1a answer-1b answer-1c answer-1d question-2 2?questiontype-2 multianswer-2a ans1answer-2b ans2answer-2c ans3answer-2d ans4





$('#maincontent').on("click", "#addquestion", function(){
  questionnumber++;

  var getquestiontype = $('input[name=questiontype]');
  questiontype = getquestiontype.filter(':checked').val();
  question = $('#question').val();
  answer1 = $('#ans1').val();
  answer2 = $('#ans2').val();
  answer3 = $('#ans3').val();
  answer4 = $('#ans4').val();

  questiondata = '<div><input type="text" id="question-'+questionnumber+'" name="question-'+questionnumber+'" value="'+question+'">\
  <input type="text" id="questiontype-'+questionnumber+'" name="questiontype-'+questionnumber+'" value="'+questiontype+'">\
  <input type="hidden" id="answer-'+questionnumber+'a" name="answer-'+questionnumber+'a" value="'+answer1+'">\
  <input type="hidden" id="answer-'+questionnumber+'b" name="answer-'+questionnumber+'b" value="'+answer2+'">\
  <input type="hidden" id="answer-'+questionnumber+'c" name="answer-'+questionnumber+'c" value="'+answer3+'">\
  <input type="hidden" id="answer-'+questionnumber+'d" name="answer-'+questionnumber+'d" value="'+answer4+'"></div>';

  $('#addquestions').append(questiondata);

});

$('#maincontent').on("click", "#writedata", function(){ //submitting questions
    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: 'admin/setup/getdata.php',
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
    return false;
  } );
```

Comment: That code snippet probably doesn't make sense to anyone but you ?

Comment: is this an array ..?

Comment: still just to help convert your array in json format or serialize it and then save it into file

Comment: It is some sort of stupid array, it is the only way i could figure out how to make it dynamic but now i have no idea how to read from it, i just used the code snippet to hold the "array"

Comment: JavaScript interpreter can't interpret a "stupid array".

Comment: Save it as a `serialized` or a `JSON` string.

Comment: how could i do that @D4V1D Adding code to make more sense hopefully

Comment: You have the solution by now i guess .

Comment: http://keeping-connected.ca/english/ This is the url, to get to the page i am editing hit the right button and then the left one

Comment: Use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) `PHP` functions.

Comment: @Franky No i don't I use that Jquery to send that data and then right it to a textfile like so   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  $$key = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  print $key.' '.$value;
  $data .= $key.' '.$value;
}
$string =  $_POST['questionbanknames'];
 $file = '../../questionbanks/' . $string . '.txt';
$handle = fopen($file, 'w+');

fwrite($handle, $data);

Comment: Its already being answered mark use `json` encode and decode.

Comment: @Franky I'm not sure how to use that to write a proper dynamic array and save it to a text file

Comment: ` $string = json_encode($_POST)` just write this to file and while fetching use `json_decode(//file content)`

Comment: Ok so I did some playing around and i can get it to make this, can it be interpreted? {"questionbanknames":"TYest","question-1":"Question 1","questiontype-1":"manual","answer-1a":"","answer-1b":"","answer-1c":"","answer-1d":"","question-2":"Question 2","questiontype-2":"multi","answer-2a":"Test","answer-2b":"not test","answer-2c":"weird","answer-2d":"wtf"}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bVk72/4/